# Two column list inside tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, double-sided, layout

I am bit struggle for list with two column layout inside box using tcolorbox. I required output as like image attached. Please suggest how to fix this, my TeX coding is below:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most,raster]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable,hooks,skins}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}

\usepackage{multicol}

\newtcolorbox{QandPbox} {breakable,enhanced,raster columns=2,width=600pt, underlay last={\node[anchor=north east] at ([yshift=0mm]frame.north east) {};}, arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,top=9pt,left=62.8pt,right=67pt,bottom=39pt,middle=0pt,enlarge left by=-100pt,enlarge right by=180pt, colback=black!30% , colbacktitle=black!30, colframe=black!30, }

\newenvironment{QandP} {\begin{QandPbox}\begin{multicols}{2}}{\end{multicols}\end{QandPbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{QandP}

\begin{enumerate} \item{} Our book is intended for senior undergraduate students of modern abstract algebra. Those more gifted in mathematics can well profit from it sooner.

\item{}Beginning graduate students who need a refresher could find it useful as well.

\item{} For pairs of small integers, their greatest common divisor can be seen by inspection.

\item{} For instance, gcd(42; 30) = 6. When the integers become large, there is an efficient technique for finding their greatest common divisor, based on repeated use of Euclidean division.

\end{enumerate}

\end{QandP}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your \AddToShipoutPictureBG appears to be one line with multiple % entries resulting in unbalanced braces.  Please add the original line breaks.

Comment: From the image I understand you want a complete section of your document to be printed with a non white background color and text in two columns. This is not a tcolorbox with two columns text inside. You can use a tcolorbox with two columns text inside, but breaking pages won't work and you will have to do it by hand. I think it's better that you clarify what's the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I removed multiple % and \AddToShipoutPictureBG command also, could you please suggest how to fix my requirement

Comment: Assuming your screen shot is a two page view, your only problem appears to be setting the overlap.  For odd pages the left margin is given by `\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin` and the right margin is whatever is left `\dimexpr \paperwidth-\textwidth-1in-\oddsidemargin`.  For even pages, use \evensidemargin instead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks for your response. My actual challenge is fix double column list inside the tcolorbox as  per attached layout. Hope this explanation is clear and your response very helpful to me. Have a nice weekend.